# I'm trying to print these 3 given objects but I'm unable to! It's showing : invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

```
class AudioDevice {
    public:
        string brand;
        string model;
        int year;
        int cost;
};
int main()
{
    AudioDevice Device1;
        Device1.brand = "Apple";
        Device1.model = "AirPods Pro";
        Device1.year = "2021";
        Device1.cost = "11999";

    AudioDevice Device2;
        Device2.brand = "boAt";
        Device2.model = "Bassheads";
        Device2.year = "2021";
        Device2.cost = "3999";

    AudioDevice Device3;
        Device3.brand = "Marshall";
        Device3.model = "Emberton";
        Device3.year = "2020";
        Device3.cost = "15499";

    cout << Device1.brand << " " << Device1.model << " " << Device1.year << " " << Device1.cost << "\n" << endl;
    
    cout << Device2.brand << " " << Device2.model << " " << Device2.year << " " << Device2.cost << "\n" << endl;
    
    cout << Device3.brand << " " << Device3.model << " " << Device3.year << " " << Device3.cost << "\n" << endl; 

return 0;
}
```

Please check whether I haven't declared a few thing. I can't see the conversion happening, where is it?
I've made a class the created 3 object(AudioDevice Device1, 2, 3 respectively). I made the same program but it takes input (which is by using cin <<). But it's a simple program as compared to that dynamic input program.
I would love it, if someone can help me fix this code.

Comment: `"123"` is not a number. `123` is.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: That remarks should have been yours ;-)

Comment: why don't you add a method to the class to dump the instance to a stream like `cout`, implement `operator<<`

Comment: why if you look at the line number given in the error message you do not get a clue what the text is about by looking at the line or the line before.

Answer (score 2):

```
Device1.year = "2021";
Device1.cost = "11999";
```

should be

```
Device1.year = 2021;
Device1.cost = 11999;
```

(similarly for other device for year/cost).

Alternatively, you might do:

```
class AudioDevice
{
public:
    std::string brand;
    std::string model;
    int year;
    int cost;
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const AudioDevice& device)
{
    return os << device.brand
              << " " << device.model
              << " " << device.year
              << " " << device.cost;
}

int main()
{
    AudioDevice devices[] = {
        { "Apple", "AirPods Pro", 2021, 11999},
        { "boAt", "Bassheads", 2021, 3999},
        { "Marshall", "Emberton", 2020, 15499}
    };
    for (const auto& device : devices) {
        std::cout << device << "\n" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PaE39GoqK)